# My laptop CPU slows down to 0.20GHZ when the battery reaches 10% and everything become laggy and unresposive is this normal?

Tags: windows, laptop, cpu, battery, windows-11

My ASUS TUF Dash F15 (Windows 11) laptop becomes unusable when the battery reaches 10%. CPU speed go down from 3Ghz To only 0.20 and the laptop become unresponsive and slow and can't even play YouTube videos, how can i fix that?

- **Processor**: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 @ 3.30GHz, 3302 Mhz, 4 Core(s)
- **BIOS Version/Date**: American Megatrends International, LLC. FX516PE.313, 30/11/2021

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: I agree, there's no question. Anyway, Battery Saver kicking in at 10%?

Comment: so the question how to solve the problem of the laptop cpu speed getting this low when the battery reach 10% or less? i mean had 2 other laptop in the past and they ran fine until the last %

Comment: Different laptops have different battery saver settings. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: It sounds like this is a design choice by your laptop manufacturer. You should ask them if this behaviour can be disabled, or otherwise not discharge your battery below 10%. Deep cycling the battery below 10% is worse than keeping it at higher levels of charge.

Answer (score 2):

> laptop become unusable when the battery reach 10% CPU speed go down
> from 3GHZ To only 0.20

That is entirely normal.  Lack of battery charge reduces the power available to run the laptop and should cause a speed step slow down for the CPU to continue to operate.

In many cases, 10% sends a critical battery charge warning - apparently not for your machine.

Plug in the machine in order to start charging.

Is there a charging issue?

You risk sudden shutdown, losing data, at such a low level.

Continued deep discharge followed by charge can also damage the battery leading to very early battery replacement. This is an expensive way to run.

Comment: no when it's charged and the battery is above 10% it run normally, but i had other 2 laptops and even when they reach 5% they didn't lag i could watch video and browse normally

Comment: 10% is a very low charge.  Plug it it to increase the charge.  10% is borderline which is why you are seeing an issue.  You are trying to run at too low a charge level.

Comment: No; it’s not normal for a mobile processor to thermal throttle down to .20 GHz. You won’t see boost frequencies but it shouldn’t be .2 GHz

Comment: I was not suggesting thermal slow down, just speed step slow down for lower battery capacity.  A slightly slower speed is lower energy to conserve battery. At a very low charge of 5 to 10% it may already be operating at a lower speed. Hard to know precisely at this low level.

Comment: I did edit my question to more clearly relate the lower charge to lower power available inside the laptop.